# What are the two styles of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm reading the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py) for matplotlib.  Under the 'Coding Styles' section, it says:

> When viewing this documentation and examples, you will find different coding styles and usage patterns.

Later...

> Of the different styles, there are two that are officially supported. Therefore, these are the preferred ways to use matplotlib.
>
> For the pyplot style...

But then in the rest of that section they never explicitly explain or mention the 'second' supported coding style.  They say something about a 'MATLAB-style' but it is unclear from the context if that is referring to the `pyplot` style (as if it is like MATLAB) or if it is a separate style itself.

**Question**

What is the second supported matplotlib coding style and how does it relate / differ from the `pyplot` style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably this part of the usage guide is a bit hard to understand in its current form. There was however an update recently ([#14223](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14223)), which might make it clearer. A preview version of this can be found here:

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface

> As noted above, there are essentially two ways to use Matplotlib:
>
> - Explicitly create figures and axes, and call methods on them (the "object-oriented (OO) style").
> - Rely on pyplot to automatically create and manage the figures and axes, and use pyplot functions for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

```
The next level down in the hierarchy is the first level of the object-oriented
interface, in which pyplot is used only for a few functions such as figure 
creation, and the user explicitly creates and keeps track of the figure and axes 
objects. At this level, the user uses pyplot to create figures, and through those 
figures, one or more axes objects can be created. These axes objects are then used 
for most plotting actions.
```

Comment: I don't believe that this has anything to do with coding styles.  It's not describing the coding style, it is more describing the API.  Although, maybe that is what they mean by coding styles?

Comment: Yes they mean the users coding style.